# Trouble compiling PHP with MySQL on Linux: MySQL installation can not be found

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm upgrading a terribly old application using PHP 7.3 and MySQL 5.5 on RHEL 7. I have to build both PHP and MySQL from source in order to put them both in custom locations. The problem is that when I run `./configure` on PHP, with the parameter `--with-pdo-mysql`, it says it can't find the MySQL installation, even though it's in the same directory.

So I've run the `./configure` command in a thousand different ways. In addition to `with-pdo-mysql`, I also passed `with-mysqli`, but that says I have the wrong version of MySQL. What am I doing wrong? This is what the command looks like right now:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/dir/utils/apache/bin/apxs \
--prefix=/dir/utils/php \
--with-config-file-path=/dir/utils/php \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--disable-cgi \
--with-zlib \
--with-gettext \
--without-pear \
--with-pdo-mysql=/dir/mysql_64/bin
```

And this is the `ls` of /dir/mysql_64/bin:

```
innochecksum       mysql                       mysql_secure_installation  mysqlaccess.conf  mysqld_safe    mysqltest
msql2mysql         mysql_client_test           mysql_setpermission        mysqladmin        mysqldump      perror
my_print_defaults  mysql_config                mysql_tzinfo_to_sql        mysqlbinlog       mysqldumpslow  replace
myisam_ftdump      mysql_convert_table_format  mysql_upgrade              mysqlbug          mysqlhotcopy   resolve_stack_dump
myisamchk          mysql_find_rows             mysql_waitpid              mysqlcheck        mysqlimport    resolveip
myisamlog          mysql_fix_extensions        mysql_zap                  mysqld            mysqlshow
myisampack         mysql_plugin                mysqlaccess                mysqld_multi      mysqlslap
```

Comment: While I don't know for sure what directory `--with-pdo-mysql` wants, I am fairly certain that it's not a bin dir. Try just `/bin/mysql_64` or leave it blank.

Comment: I haven't used RPM based distros for ages, but I think you can customise the installation location: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-install-an-rpm-package-into-a-different-directory-in-centos-rhel-fedora/ - Another thing is, I guess, if you want to install different conflicting packages at once.